# Datetime unknown binary format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, binary

I have the following array of bytes:

```
Byte[] date = { 0x00, 0xf1, 0x04, 0x80, 0x0f, 0xca, 0xa8, 0x62 };
```

Unfortunately i have no idea how to convert it to a `DateTime` type.

The only hint that i have is that the "date" part is 10/24/2015 (mm/dd/yyyy), the "time" part exist, but i don't know.

I'm already tried the conversions:

```
var firstAttempt = DateTime.FromBinary(0x00f104800fcaa862);
var secondAttempt = DateTime.FromFileTime(0x00f104800fcaa862);
var thirdAttempt = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0x00f104800fcaa862);
var fourthAttempt = DateTime.FromOADate(0x00f104800fcaa862);
var fifthAttempt = new DateTime(0x00f104800fcaa862);
```

But with no success.

someone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you even know this is a date and time, and not something else entirely?

Comment: An application send me this byte array using the TCP/IP connection, I think it was written in Delphi and unfortunately there is no message format documentation.

Comment: I know that this range of bytes is a DateTime because I could understand and convert all other message properties, only left this field that I could not translate into DateTime.

Comment: These numbers could mean anything. Pass through more dates and collect the results (change just the month or year for example) and see if you can find any trends.

Comment: Almost any machine you'd work with is little-endian, certainly one that runs Delphi.  So you are interpreting the bytes backwards, it should be 0x62a8.. and not 0x00f1....  That still doesn't get you anywhere, you really **do** have to use a telephone.  We can't help you make that call.

Comment: @HansPassant Do a phone call and ask about the format of this datetime would certainly be the quickest way. Unfortunately I have recurred to StackOverflow because that person no longer exists.

Comment: @AnthonySherratt Thats a great idea, i'll try to get more values to identify patterns. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the information provided is not sufficient to form an answer.  Please either refer to the source of your data, or edit your question to provide several variations such that it may be possible to discern a pattern.  As written, the question is not answerable.

Comment: Yes, let's see some more samples - both of the same date and for different dates.

Comment: @HélioTibagí Well, did the application crash?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your binary representation of the date is correct? 
It looks like 10/24/2015 should look like **0x8D2DC060F768000**.

If your Input is correct and it is a different kind of a binary converter - you'll need your own parser. Or some kind of modification of the data source (so it could return string representation for instance)

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.  It belongs in comments.

Comment: No. I think that the *0x00f104800fcaa862* was made using a different way that can represent 10/24/2015. Like some funny datatypes in some plataforms that the date is represented with a double type.

Comment: Do you have an access to the DataSource so you could use string converted to the Byte Array instead? Playing with the different dates could help, but it is not the most reliable solution

Comment: Nope, this datetime data is like a **DateTime.Now** that the server application sent to me, is created in memory. Unfortunately I can not use a **DateTime.Now** in my application side, because there are unpredictable delays.

Comment: @HélioTibagí - Run it on a few different days, capturing the value from each.  Then come back and update your question.  Knowing how the value changes from day to day will help decipher this.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Sure, i'll do it. Thanks.